# mongoexport Issue for array values

Tags: mongodb

While exporting the records as a CSV file format for the array values, this list of array values are not placing in a single cell and placing in subsequent columns.
I have done below steps and got this output. Please help me to resolve this issue

mongoexport --db gls_v2 --collection assignment --out assignment.csv

Output in excel
Column1           Column2   Column3 Column4 
Maths theorems    201       403      574
Science Topic -2  281       445      489
Science Topic -1  391       400

Expected output
Column1            Column2
Maths theorems     201,403,574
Science Topic -2   281,445,489
Science Topic -1   391,400

Comment: The command with options as listed would output as JSON and not CSV. For CSV output you need the `--type csv` option as well as `--fields` being also required.

Comment: Since i got the csv file successfully as an output, i have seen the issue that array values are displaying in subsequent columns instead of displaying in a single cell. But now its displaying correctly as you said that array value placed in a single cell. Thank you so much